# Why do most exceptions omit instance-specific information?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I've noticed that most exception messages don't include instance-specific details like the value that caused the exception. They generally only tell you the "category" of the error.

For example, when attempting to serialize an object with a 3rd. party library, I got a MissingMethodException with message:

> "No parameterless constructor defined for this object."

In many cases this is enough, but often (typically during development) a message like

> "No parameterless constructor defined for this object of type 'Foo'."

can save a lot of time by directing you straight to the cause of the error.

InvalidArgumentException is another example: it usually tells you the name of the argument but not its value.
This seems to be the case for most framework-raised exceptions, but also for 3rd party libraries.

**Is this done on purpose?**

Is there a security implication in exposing an internal state like the "faulty" value of a variable?

Comment: I feel your pain. "Key not found in Dictionary" is another one that drives me mad. Which key!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two reasons I can think of:

Firstly, maybe the parameter that threw the exception was a value that was a processed form of the one that was passed to the public interface. The value may not make sense without the expense of catching to rethrow a different exception that is going to be the same in most regards anyway.

Secondly, and more importantly, is that there can indeed be a security risk, that can be very hard to second-guess (if I'm writing a general-purpose container, I don't know what contexts it will be used in). We don't want "Credit-Card: 5555444455554444" appearing in an error message if we can help it.

Ultimately, just what debug information is most useful will vary according to the error anyway. If the type, method and (when possible) file and line number isn't enough, it's time to write some debug code that traps just what you do want to know, rather than complaining that it isn't already trapped when next time you might want yet different information (field state of instances can be just as likely to be useful as parameters).

Comment: About your 3rd point: sometimes an application 'calls home' with a stacktrace and I've seen cases where filename/linenumber leave you scratching the head. Knowing what value caused the error can be useful in those cases, however I agree that the security risk is definitely not worth it.

Comment: @FrancescoDeVittori "Calling home" is a nuisance alright, and that I would more often consider a flaw. Ideally an exception should be thrown at a public member, but if applicable contain an InnerException that details what went wrong deeper in, in case that really is where the bug was. Of course, if you think your public member can't possibly throw, then you won't have done this (then again, if you think that, then either it was your bug not the caller's, or it was the caller's bug plus your bug in how you handled their bug).

Answer (score 4):

`InvalidArgumentException` and (per @Ian Nelson) "Key not found in dictionary" both share something in common - there's no guarantee that the framework would be able to find a suitable value to show you - if the key/argument is of any user defined type, and `ToString()` hasn't been overridden, then you would just get the type name - it's not going to add a lot of value.

Comment: This can a valid reason indeed.

Comment: Moreover ToString() method might throw an exception, which would mess the callstack completely :)

Answer (score 2):

Exceptions are mostly meant for a program to consume. Most programs wouldn't know what to do with information about the instance.

The `Message` property is aimed at human consumption. Other than in a debugging scenario, humans won't know what to make of `Foo`.

Comment: Other than in a debugging scenario, humans wouldn't know what to make of "No parameterless constructor defined for this object."

Comment: Ok, but most exception messages are not presented as-is to the end user. When not debugging they are usually discarded or wrapped into an error report/log/etc.. To a user KeyNotFoundException does not make more sense than 'Foo' as well.

Answer (score 1):

Many exception mechanisms try to serve a hodgepodge of orthogonal purposes by passing a single exception-derived object:

1. Letting the caller know that various specific things have happened, or that various specific problems exist.

   Determining when the exceptional condition is "resolved" so that normal program flow can continue.

   Providing an indication of what to tell the user of the program

   Providing information which could be logged to allow the owners of a system to identify problems, when a secure log is available

   Providing information which could be logged to allow the owners of a system to identify problems, but which would not pose a security risk even if secure logging is not available.

Unfortunately, I'm unaware of any exception mechanism in widespread use which can actually accomplish all five of the above, well.